# onClick enable form

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have problem when i want show form edit

```html
<!-- this is form-->
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>No</th><th>Company Name</th><th>City</th><th>State</th><th>Zip</th><th>Branch</th><th>Address</th><th>Edit</th><th>Delete</th>
        </tr> 
    </thead>
<% while(resultset.next()){ %>
    <tbody>
        <form method='POST' action='EditCompany'>
            <tr align='center'>
                <td><%= no %></td>
                <td><input id='f1' class="form-control btn-no-border" type="text" disabled="disabled" value='<%= resultset.getString(2)%>'></td> 
                <td><input id='f2' class="form-control btn-no-border" type="text" disabled="disabled" value='<%= resultset.getString(3)%>'></td> 
                <td><input id='f3'class="form-control btn-no-border" type="text" disabled="disabled" value='<%= resultset.getString(4)%>'></td> 
                <td><input id='f4' class="form-control btn-no-border" type="text" disabled="disabled" value='<%= resultset.getString(5)%>'></td> 
                <td><input id='f5' class="form-control btn-no-border" type="text" disabled="disabled" value='<%= resultset.getString(6)%>'></td> 
                <td><input id='f6' class="form-control btn-no-border" type="text" disabled="disabled" value='<%= resultset.getString(7)%>'></td>
                <td><a id='elementId' onclick="showDiv()"><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span></a> <input type='submit' id="welcomeDiv" style="display:none;"></td>
                <td><a href="#" data-href="DeleteCompany?id=<%= resultset.getString(1)%>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-delete"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a></td>
            </tr>
        </form>
    </tbody>
<% no++; } %> 
</table>
```

The form will enable when the glypicon edit click. Here is the
JAVASCRIPT :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showDiv() {
        document.getElementById('welcomeDiv').style.display = "block";
    }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $('#elementId').click(function(){
        $('#f1').removeAttr("disabled");
        $('#f2').removeAttr("disabled");
        $('#f3').removeAttr("disabled");
        $('#f4').removeAttr("disabled");
        $('#f5').removeAttr("disabled");
        $('#f6').removeAttr("disabled");
        $('#f7').removeAttr("disabled"); 
    });
</script>
```

when `<a id='elementId' onclick="showDiv()"><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span></a> <input type='submit' id="welcomeDiv" style="display:none;">` click
for first row, work.

[image]

but for the second row like this

[image]

Comment: i think this this is because all the button have the same id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically when you click on AAA then it is removing the class "aaa" from input field. You can check it with Firebug . It is not showing or popping up anything in it. But I have written a new code. It will enable and disable the input

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>No</th><th>Company Name</th><th>City</th><th>State</th><th>Zip</th><th>Branch</th><th>Address</th><th>Edit</th><th>Delete</th>
        </tr> 
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <form method='POST' action='EditCompany'>
            <tr align='center'>
                <td>1</td>
                <td><input type="text" class="aaa" value ="kool" disabled="disabled"/></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="aaa" value ="fool" disabled="disabled"/></td>
                <td class="abc">AAA</td>
            </tr>
        </form>
    </tbody>

</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function showDiv() {
        document.getElementById('welcomeDiv').style.display = "block";
    }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $('.abc').click(function(){
  $(this).closest('tr').find('.aaa').attr('disabled',false);
        
        
    });
</script>
```

box.

Comment: it works. but I need your help again. how to show input submit?
like my issues above

Comment: and how to back unable form when another row onClick

Answer (score 1):

You are repeating the same id on one page. You must use only one id on a page. You can use the same class multiple times but not id.

Answer (score 0):

A small example to do for this:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>No</th><th>Company Name</th><th>City</th><th>State</th><th>Zip</th><th>Branch</th><th>Address</th><th>Edit</th><th>Delete</th>
        </tr> 
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <form method='POST' action='EditCompany'>
            <tr align='center'>
                <td>1</td>
                <td><input type="text" class="aaa"/></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="aaa"/></td>
                <td class="abc">AAA</td>
            </tr>
        </form>
    </tbody>

</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function showDiv() {
        document.getElementById('welcomeDiv').style.display = "block";
    }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $('.abc').click(function(){
  
        $(this).closest('tr').find('.aaa').removeClass('aaa');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: sorry, when i try. it doing nothing

Answer (score 0):

In this way you are just referring to closest element of click.You can modified any content based on this. Please feel free to ask any query, if you face any problem in it. I just shared an example for execution for this. 
This is applicable for any number of rows in a table.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>No</th><th>Company Name</th><th>City</th><th>State</th><th>Zip</th><th>Branch</th><th>Address</th><th>Edit</th><th>Delete</th>
        </tr> 
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <form method='POST' action='EditCompany'>
            <tr align='center'>
                <td>1</td>
                <td><input type="text" class="aaa" value ="kool" disabled="disabled"/></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="aaa" value ="fool" disabled="disabled"/></td>
                <td class="abc">AAA</td>
            </tr>
        </form>
    </tbody>

</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function showDiv() {
        document.getElementById('welcomeDiv').style.display = "block";
    }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $('.abc').click(function(){
  $(this).closest('tr').find('.aaa').attr('disabled',false);
        
        $(this).closest('tr td:eq(2)').find('a:eq(0)').show();
      $(this).closest('tr td:eq(2)').find('a:eq(1)').hide();
      // Or YOu can use
      $(this).closest('tr td:eq(2)').find('a:eq(0)').css('display','block');
      $(this).closest('tr td:eq(2)').find('a:eq(0)').css('display','none');
    });
</script>
```

Please refer eq:(COlUMN of TR). It starts from zero so make adjustment accordingly. Hope you get complete answer of your query.

Answer (score 0):

Add some class in tr.

```html
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $('.abc').click(function(){
        $('trClassName').find('.aaa').attr('disabled',true);
  $(this).closest('tr').find('.aaa').attr('disabled',false);
        
        
    });
</script>
```

Hope it will solve all your problems.

Answer (score 0):

Only add class in tbody tr and also it should be with dot in jquery syntax.I have mentioned classname and it should also be with .TrClassName which you will mention in tr.

Comment: <tr align='center' class='form'>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $('.abc').click(function(){
        $('.form').find('.aaa').attr('disabled',true);
  $(this).closest('tr').find('.aaa').attr('disabled',false);
        
        
    });
</script> like this?

Comment: Yes, It should work. It will disabled all the tr td input and enable the latest click on tr.

Comment: thank you for your kind hearted. I am so thankful to you. but I forget one thing anymore. How to make it the same button for toggle enable and disable. Sorry I am too many ask some question. This site is so useful for beginner like me.